# How to Change the Landscape Directory in SAP Business one Form Business One client?

Tags: sapb1

In Local Are Network is Disconnected. that time I was Open SAP Business one Client is Asking For System Landscape Directory. I was Change the IP Address for Another Machine. I really Don't Know How to Change Before Connected Machine. and What is the Landscape Directory in SAP Business One?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step1:**

Open the Service Manager -> Settings->Configure Security

**Step2:**

In Browser Launch and Go to Servers and Companies Menu

**Step3:**

Server Page -> Add Button Click

**Step4:**

Add the Server Name, User Name and password.